# Hibernate only works when class is final [otherwise SingleTableEntityPersister is thrown]

Tags: java, scala, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I have tried to build very simple entity and persist it in a db using Hibernate 5.4.1.Final and Java8. To eliminate state mutation "setters" are skipped and  @Access(AccessType.FIELD) is used instead. Unfortunately when Hibernate boots up, this exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [application-context.repositories.xml]:
    Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
    [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: 
    Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
```

I found out that after making Product class final everything works. The problem is, I do not understand why??? **Could you help me to understand what is happening?**

A bit of code.
This does not work:

```
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Getter
  private String name;

  @Getter
  private String colour;

  protected Product() {
  }

  @Builder
  public Product(String name, String colour) {
    this.name = name;
    this.colour = colour;
  }
}
```

bit it is enough to add final

```
public final class Product {
```

and it works.

application-context.repositories.xml only inform spring where repositories are

```
  <jpa:repositories base-package="a.b.c.repositories"/>
```

While debuging I also found out that one of the underling exception is

```
HibernateException ->  Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
```

Any ideas why is "final" required?

// edit

Andronicus pointed proper direction:

Now I know that if class is not final, hibernate tries to build a proxy and exception comes from 
ByteBuddyProxyHelper.class

```
return byteBuddyState.loadProxy( persistentClass, new TypeCache.SimpleKey(key), byteBuddy -> byteBuddy
        .ignore( byteBuddyState.getProxyDefinitionHelpers().getGroovyGetMetaClassFilter() )
        .with( new NamingStrategy.SuffixingRandom( PROXY_NAMING_SUFFIX, new NamingStrategy.SuffixingRandom.BaseNameResolver.ForFixedValue( persistentClass.getName() ) ) )
        .subclass( interfaces.length == 1 ? persistentClass : Object.class, ConstructorStrategy.Default.IMITATE_SUPER_CLASS_OPENING )
        .implement( (Type[]) interfaces )
        .method( byteBuddyState.getProxyDefinitionHelpers().getVirtualNotFinalizerFilter() )
                .intercept( byteBuddyState.getProxyDefinitionHelpers().getDelegateToInterceptorDispatcherMethodDelegation() )
        .method( byteBuddyState.getProxyDefinitionHelpers().getHibernateGeneratedMethodFilter() )
                .intercept( SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE )
        .defineField( ProxyConfiguration.INTERCEPTOR_FIELD_NAME, ProxyConfiguration.Interceptor.class, Visibility.PRIVATE )
        .implement( ProxyConfiguration.class )
                .intercept( byteBuddyState.getProxyDefinitionHelpers().getInterceptorFieldAccessor() )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, why with the `final` keyword it works, maybe it has something to do with proxy generation. Here the problem is `@Builder` from lombok I think. A [bug](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/816) has been reported, that adding `@Builder` annotation removes the default constructor, that is needed by hibernate.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It helped me to move step forward. I would love to upvote - but 15 reputation is needed - so I cannot yet

Comment: Now you're almost there:) you can mark this answer as correct to help other with the same problem

Comment: I was able to upovte - but correct answer is different :)

Answer (score 1):

So, days of debugging led me to:

```
    public static ClassLoadingStrategy<ClassLoader> resolveClassLoadingStrategy(Class<?> originalClass) {
        // This is available only for JDK 9+
        if ( !ClassInjector.UsingLookup.isAvailable() ) {
            return new ClassLoadingStrategy.ForUnsafeInjection( originalClass.getProtectionDomain() );
        }

        Method privateLookupIn;
        try {
            privateLookupIn = MethodHandles.class.getMethod( "privateLookupIn", Class.class, MethodHandles.Lookup.class );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HibernateException( LOG.bytecodeEnhancementFailed( originalClass.getName() ), e );
        }
```

ClassInjector.UsingLookup.isAvailable() - on Java8 throws NoMethodError which is swallowed by Hibernate